# Help to test email provider

Tags: exploratory, email

I recently started working for an Email provider company as a QA. However, I never had to test encrypted emails before, and am a bit lost. Has anyone here tested emails before? If so, I would appreciate if I could get some help in how to be accurate on my test and on my test plan and acceptance criteria.

Comment: How have people in the company tested their work so far?

Comment: You probably can ask your company what needs to be tested, how they have tested before, etc.